# Google plus url sharing

Tags: javascript, url, encoding, google-plus

I use this link for sharing my page via google plus.

```
 https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcompany%20name%2search
```

so I use encodeURIComponent for getting this url (also tried to use encodeURI).
but when sharing box appears link is incorrect. It is:

```
 http://example.com/company
```

Forsure I can change ' ' with, for example,  '-' (or another symbol), but I use value from url in my AngulaJs app for correct initializing and it will be better to use native way for this.

What is my fault or are there any native ways to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%20` is an encoded space which is not a valid URL character. The most commonly used character instead of a space is a `-`.

The best approach would be to normalize the input into an ID that you will use to query your own database. E.g. `Bob's Bar & Grill` would get processed to `bobs-bar-grill` and then you would query your database to find:

```
{
    "id": "bobs-bar-grill",
    "name": "Bob's Bar & Grill"
}
```

This both makes your URLs clean and better protects you from a security perspective of random user content in URLs.

As a last resort you could double encode the path so that Google still has encoded spaces after it decodes the URL once.

```
var url = "http://example.com/company name";
encodeURI(encodeURI(url));
// "http://example.com/company%2520name"
```

And Google will send users to `http://example.com/company%20name`

Comment: it's not a constant there (not 'my profile'), but some vendor name. So I want to use some native way to encode/decode the url. For sure I can add some symbol like '-'. But it's angularJs app and I use value from url when app is initialized. so it will be necessary to remove this '-' symbol after.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the recommended option and a last resort.

Comment: I have already fixed it myself.
In any way thanks. I'll mark your answer as correct.